# Pass inputstream variable between classes

Tags: java, string, class, instance, nmea

I have three classes that I am working with. 
The first class opens the GPS and reads the data. 
The second parses the data. 
The third is going to be the parsed data in a GUI.

My question is how do I pass the global variable gpsData to classC from NMEA?

I am using code that I found online for the gps data.

It looks like the NMEA class is dependent on serialGps and serialGps is dependent on NMEA.

I need to pass the inputLine which sets the global variable "gpsData" contained in the NMEA class to a third class which will be my GUI.

This is the serialGps class

```
 package gpsData;


import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess"})
public class SerialGps {

    public interface StateListener {
        void onGpsStateUpdated(NMEA.GpsState state);
    }

    private String portName;
    private int baudRate;
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private List<StateListener> stateListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public SerialGps(String portName, int baudRate) {
        this.portName = portName;
        this.baudRate = baudRate;
    }

    public SerialGps(String portName) {
        this(portName, 4800);
    }

    public void addStateListener(StateListener stateListener) {
        stateListeners.add(stateListener);
    }

    public void start() {
        NMEA nmea = new NMEA();


        SerialPort[] serialPorts = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        SerialPort gpsPort = null;

        for (SerialPort serialPort : serialPorts) {
            if (serialPort.getDescriptivePortName().toLowerCase().contains("serial")) {
                gpsPort = serialPort;


            }
        }

        if (gpsPort == null) {
            System.out.println("failed to find gps serial port");

            return;
        }

        System.out.println("using serial port: " + gpsPort.getDescriptivePortName());

        gpsPort.setBaudRate(4800);
        gpsPort.openPort();
        InputStream inStream = gpsPort.getInputStream();


        if (inStream == null) {
            System.out.println("opening port " + gpsPort.getDescriptivePortName() + " failed");

            return;
        }

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            String inputLine = "";

            isRunning = true;

            while (isRunning) {
                try {
                    if (inStream.available() > 0) {
                        char b = (char) inStream.read();

                        if (b == '\n') {
                            NMEA.GpsState gpsState = nmea.getUpdatedStatus(inputLine);

                            updateState(gpsState);

                            inputLine = "";
                        } else {
                            inputLine += b;
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        thread.start();

    }

    public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    private void updateState(NMEA.GpsState gpsState) {
        stateListeners.forEach(stateListener -> stateListener.onGpsStateUpdated(gpsState));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SerialGps app = new SerialGps("/dev/cu.usbserial", 4800);
    app.start();




    }
}
```

The NMEA class:

```
    package gpsData;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class NMEA {
    public static String gpsData = null;
    interface SentenceParser {
        boolean parse(String[] tokens, GpsState position);
    }


    private class GPGGA implements SentenceParser {
        public boolean parse(String[] tokens, GpsState position) {
            position.time = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            position.lat = Latitude2Decimal(tokens[2], tokens[3]);
            position.lon = Longitude2Decimal(tokens[4], tokens[5]);
            position.quality = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]);
            position.altitude = Float.parseFloat(tokens[9]);

            return true;
        }
    }

    private class GPGGL implements SentenceParser {
        public boolean parse(String[] tokens, GpsState position) {
            position.lat = Latitude2Decimal(tokens[1], tokens[2]);
            position.lon = Longitude2Decimal(tokens[3], tokens[4]);
            position.time = Float.parseFloat(tokens[5]);

            return true;
        }
    }

    private class GPRMC implements SentenceParser {
        public boolean parse(String[] tokens, GpsState position) {
            position.time = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            position.lat = Latitude2Decimal(tokens[3], tokens[4]);
            position.lon = Longitude2Decimal(tokens[5], tokens[6]);
            position.velocity = Float.parseFloat(tokens[7]);
            position.dir = Float.parseFloat(tokens[8]);

            return true;
        }
    }

    private class GPVTG implements SentenceParser {
        public boolean parse(String[] tokens, GpsState position) {
            position.dir = Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]);

            return true;
        }
    }

    private class GPRMZ implements SentenceParser {
        public boolean parse(String[] tokens, GpsState position) {
            position.altitude = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);

            return true;
        }
    }

    private static float Latitude2Decimal(String lat, String NS) {
        float result = (Float.parseFloat(lat.substring(2)) / 60.0f) + Float.parseFloat(lat.substring(0, 2));

        if (NS.startsWith("S")) {
            result *= -1.0f;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static float Longitude2Decimal(String lon, String WE) {
        float med = (Float.parseFloat(lon.substring(3)) / 60.0f) + Float.parseFloat(lon.substring(0, 3));

        if (WE.startsWith("W")) {
            med *= -1.0f;
        }

        return med;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    public class GpsState {
        public float time = 0.0f;
        public float lat = 0.0f;
        public float lon = 0.0f;
        public boolean hasFix = false;
        public int quality = 0;
        public float dir = 0.0f;
        public float altitude = 0.0f;
        public float velocity = 0.0f;

        void updatefix() {
            hasFix = quality > 0;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("POSITION: lat: %f, lon: %f, time: %f, Q: %d, dir: %f, alt: %f, vel: %f", lat, lon, time, quality, dir, altitude, velocity);
        }
    }

    private GpsState position = new GpsState();

    private static final Map<String, SentenceParser> sentenceParsers = new HashMap<>();

    NMEA() {
        sentenceParsers.put("GPGGA", new GPGGA());
        sentenceParsers.put("GPGGL", new GPGGL());
        sentenceParsers.put("GPRMC", new GPRMC());
        sentenceParsers.put("GPRMZ", new GPRMZ());
        sentenceParsers.put("GPVTG", new GPVTG());

    }


    GpsState getUpdatedStatus(String inputLine) {

        if (inputLine.startsWith("$")) {
              //System.out.println(inputLine);
            String nmea = inputLine.substring(1);
            String[] tokens = nmea.split(",");
            String type = tokens[0];
            this.gpsData = inputLine;
            //System.out.println(gpsData);


            if (sentenceParsers.containsKey(type)) {
                try {

                    sentenceParsers.get(type).parse(tokens, position);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }

            position.updatefix();
            //System.out.println(gpsData);
        }


        return position;
    }

public static String passer() {
    String gpsData2 = gpsData;
    return gpsData2;
}

}
```

classC

```
    package gpsData;

public class classC {
    static String inputLinet = null;

    public void print() {
        inputLinet = NMEA.gpsData;
        if (inputLinet.startsWith("$")) {
            System.out.print(inputLinet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not favor this design.  Streams are read once assets.  Better to read all the data into a List of Strings, close the stream, and pass the contents around for processing.

Comment: Its for a gps tracking program so the stream will be open for hours at a time.

Comment: ```public static String gpsData``` is, well, public and static, so anyone can access it any time as ```NMEA.gpsData``` - just like how it appears in ```classC```. And all of this has very little to do with "Pass inputstream variable between classes". You should consider describing what you want to happen, and not how you want it to happen.

Comment: Even worse.  This is a terrible design.  Rethink it in terms of events.

Comment: What I want to happen is to use a parser within my GUI class to parse gpsData. SerialGps (read gps) --> NMEA (inputLine --> gpsData) -->classC (parsed values from gpsData to display)

Comment: Better design, UI takes a source of parsed events, parser provides this, and takes in a source of NMEA messages, then new events can flow to the UI

Comment: Global variables and "stream open for hours" are the hallmarks of what not to do.  When you find yourself thinking that either one is a good idea you should reconsider.

Comment: so how would you make a gps tracker app while not having a stream of data open for hours? This app is for my own personal use. It will not be released. I just need to figure out how to access the gps data stream in my GUI.